# TCPDF each() is deprecated function under PHP 7.3

Tags: php, tcpdf, deprecation-warning, fpdi, php-7.3

You may have an error back using TDPDF, error saying

each() function is deprecated, error in fpdi.php line 562

Answer (score 3):

Here is the working solution on my system:

```
    //while (list($k, $v) = each($value[1])) {   //orignal line 562
    foreach ($value[1] as $k => $v ) {               //new line 562
        $this->_straightOut($k . ' ');
        $this->_writeValue($v);
    }
```